# How to render Latin 1 characters correctly using coldfusion 11 and pdf document

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, character-encoding

I am having trouble getting the latin character `ä` to display correctly in a pdf generated from ColdFusion code. I get `Ã¤` instead of `ä`. I am setting cfprocessing directive to UTF-8. I can hardcode `&auml` and get the `ä` character displaying correctly in the pdf. So the pdf can handle displaying the character.

Most posts refer to a mismatch of encoding that is causing this mojibake, but I can't see where there is any mismatch. The value being used as input into the pdf document is coming from a form (ColdFusion) that takes user input and the form tag in CF code has this property set:

```
accept-charset="utf-8"
```

On the input form, and in the cfm file handling the submit, the processing directive is set to UTF-8.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce what you described w/CF11. Can you post your CF version and a [simple repro case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: No..i can't post my code..but I did end up solving my issue. It was obviously an encoding mismatch and because the user entered data is passed to another cfm page via javascript logic I was guessing that I was getting a one-byte character represention...which cannot display latin-1...so i played around with the CharsetDecode and CharsetEncode methods. I decoded the user string using windows-1252 and then encoded it using utf-8, and voila..no more issues. Not real happy with my solution, but after a couple of days of playing with it i was happy to "beat" it finally.

Comment: Oh...and I am using CF11

Comment: No, not your full code ;-), just a small example that reproduces the issue.  Isolate the problem by extracting only the relevant bits of code and using them to create a small, *standalone* example that reproduces the problem. In your case, a simple form with a single text field and a basic cfdocument call using that one form field. ie Basically what you normally do as part of the troubleshooting process.  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW, cfprocessingdirective is only necessary when hard coding the characters into the cfm script. *Not real happy with my solution* If you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35136452/edit) a small repro case, I am sure someone can assist with finding a more robust solution.

Comment: it would be too difficult to provide a small example. The values go from a form on one cfm page to another cfm page..through javascript...back to another. From all the reading I did, when passing variables through URLs etc the character encoding can only be one byte.  Detecting the exact encoding is not trivial...and never 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up solving my issue. It was obviously an encoding mismatch and because the user entered data is passed to another cfm page via javascript logic I was guessing that I was getting a one-byte character represention...which cannot display latin-1...so i played around with the CharsetDecode and CharsetEncode methods. I decoded the user string using windows-1252 and then encoded it using utf-8, and voila..no more issues. Not real happy with my solution, but after a couple of days of playing with it i was happy to "beat" it finally.